# ART library does not work in react native

Tags: android, react-native

I try to use ART library in react-native build in android phone, but no matter what I put in Shape aways rendering a black image, like this:

[image]

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
ART,
StyleSheet,
View,
Button,
} from 'react-native';

const {
Group,
Shape,
Surface,
} = ART;


export default class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Surface width={500} height={500}>
                <Group x={0} y={0}>
                    <Shape
                      d="M10 80 C 40 10, 65 10, 95 80 S 150 150, 180 80"
                      stroke="#555"
                      strokeWidth={1}
                     />
                </Group>
            </Surface>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The ART library in React Native does not support Android that well. There are loads of issues. The following being an example that links to yours fairly well i think:

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17565

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17565#issuecomment-430897843

I would say try some of the solutions in the links above. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

The appState solution in [react-native-circular-progress](https://github.com/bartgryszko/react-native-circular-progress/commit/f198080ef269db0064ac5363de50a0ad98c3028a) works for me. I did have the issue when the ART was loaded on the initial screen. In that case calling setState twice within the appState handler seemed to solve the problem.

```
_handleAppStateChange = (nextAppState) => {
    this.setState({ appState: 'random_value' });
    this.setState({ appState: nextAppState });
}
```